# How to find which TensorFlow is installed in my windows system? Whether it is CPU or GPU TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, prompt

I tried out the following command on the *Anaconda command prompt*,

```
pip show tensorflow
```

which gave me the result,

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.10.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: d:\softwares\pycond\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages
Requires: termcolor, absl-py, grpcio, tensorboard, wheel, protobuf, gast, six, numpy, setuptools, astor
```

I want to know if the installed TensorFlow is CPU supported or GPU supported. How can I get this information?

Comment: `pip show tensorflow-gpu` , `pip list | grep tensorflow-gpu` , `python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.test.gpu_device_name())'`

Comment: do you have access to anaconda navigator?

Answer (score 1):

The TensorFlow pip package includes GPU support for CUDA®-enabled cards

```
pip show tensorflow
```

For Older versions of TensorFlow:

For releases 1.15 and older, CPU and GPU packages are separate:

```
pip install tensorflow==1.15      # CPU
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15  # GPU
```

So, package names are different in for releases 1.15 and older.